# What do you mean by sensitive slicers?

Tags: pcie

In Pcie Gen5 overview, the receiver can detect the eye opening at 10mV. This require sensitive slicers to be design to capture the Eye height as low as 10mV.

Can anybody explain what is sensitive slicers here? Is that the sensitivity of the  receiver.?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, a *slicer* is something like a combination of a comparator and a D flip-flop.

The comparator functionality means that it can very accurately detect whether the input is above or below some threshold. Often, the threshold is adjustable.

The flip-flop functionality means that the comparator result is captured at a very specific instant in time, according to the clock input of the circuit.

In the case of the receiver for a digital transmission system like PCIe, some algorithm would be used to optimize the threshold level and the timing of the clock signal to minimize the error rate of the system.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot for my understanding.